# Get fields from object

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I have collection Country with fields: name, aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd.

Example:

```
{_id: xxx1, name: "USA", aaa: "daf", ccc: "sdfgsdf", ddd: "234"}
{_id: xxx2, name: "Mexico", aaa: "dfg", bbb: "fdsgsdf"}
{_id: xxx3, name: "Germany", bbb: "ddfgaf"}
{_id: xxx4, name: "France"}
```

In controller in my Symfony application I get alls objects to variable $countries and next:

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    //how can I get here fields for current object? 
    //For _id: xxx1 I would like receive "_id, name, aaa, ccc, ddd" and for _id: xxx4 I would like receive "_id, name"
}
```

Comment: Is there a question that you wanted to ask?

Comment: It seems to be embedded as a comment in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_object_vars() and array_keys() inside your foreach.

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {
   $fields = array_keys(get_object_vars($country)); 
}
```